# Alfresco 6.2 - Scheduled Jobs

Tags: alfresco, scheduler

I have created a scheduled job to update a node property in Alfresco 6.2 Enterprise instance.

I get following error while trying to update the node property.

03271369 Access Denied. The system is currently in read-only mode.

However, I am able to update node properties from script. This error message is thrown only from scheduled job.

Anybody has an idea about this?

Thank you.

Comment: What user are you running the scheduled job as?

Comment: Are you getting this on system bootstrap?  Also what @Gagravarr said, try using "AuthenticationUtil" class to authenticate.

Comment: I am running job as admin. 

I get this read-only mode error only when trying to update a node property from the job. I have AuthenticationUtil as well, it did not help.

Comment: Same issue I am also facing. any solution?

Comment: Try to change injected services to upper-case (i.e. nodeService to NodeService)